# How to pass an NSString to a function that calls printf?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to pass an NSString and list of args to printf but the compiler is unhappy about NSString not being a constant

I'd like to have a function like this:

```
+ (void)logFormat:(NSString *)format logArguments:(va_list)args {
    printf(format,args);
}
```

Is there a way to mark the parameter NSString in such a way that it makes what I'm trying to do "safe"?

EDIT: I tried declaring the parameter as const NSString * but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try `printf(format.UTF8String, args);`.

Comment: @Avi That'll fail if the format string has a '%@' sequence in it.

Comment: Would that not be because of a limitation in `printf()`, though?  In other words, isn't that an unrelated problem with the OP's approach?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:arguments:` to create a fully formatted `NSString` object, then write the contents of that via `printf`.

Since it is fully formatted, you might as well just dump it straight to `stdout` via `fwrite()` or use `NSFileHandle`.